# Getting image from network using bitmap

Tags: android, listview, bitmap

We know that each YouTube video has an image . We can get the source of that image using jsonc file. I have written a code to get the source of that image and then store it in a string in order to use bit map to put it in an image view in my costume list view.
In parsing I have no problem  I can store the source of the image.
But when my costume view is on view the image did not appear in it.
I have been told that getting the image from the network is very very bad thing and not to  do network call on UI thread .
And I should and must use some library to manage and cache bitmaps.
What can I do in order to solve this?

Here is my main activity where I did the parsing from jsonc file:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection;
import org.apache.http.protocol.HTTP;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.json.JSONTokener;


import com.example.tstnetconnwithjson.tables.custome;
import com.example.tstnetconnwithjson.tables.videos;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.AlertDialog.Builder;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {



    Button search; ; 
    TextView name ; 
    ListView listview ; 
    ArrayList<videos > videolist; 
    ArrayAdapter< videos > adapter ; 
    AlertDialog.Builder alert ; 
    ProgressDialog progressdialog ; 
    EditText name;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        videolist = new ArrayList<videos>(); 
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<videos>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 , android.R.id.text1,videolist); 
        name=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        alert = new Builder(this); 
        alert.setTitle("Warnning" ) ; 
        alert.setMessage("You want to connect to the internet ..? " ); 


        alert.setNegativeButton("No ", null); 
        alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                String username=name.getText().toString();
                            new connection().execute("https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?author="+username+"&v=2&alt=jsonc");   

            }
        });



        progressdialog = new ProgressDialog(this); 

        progressdialog.setMessage("Wait Loading .... "); 
        progressdialog.setCancelable(false); 





        search = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1); 
        name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1); 

        listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1); 

        listview.setAdapter(adapter); 


        search.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View arg0) {
            alert.show();   


            }
        });
    }

    class connection extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>{


        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
             progressdialog.show(); 
            super.onPreExecute();
        }
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {

            String s = GetUrlBody(arg0[0]); 




            return s;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        try{

            JSONObject jo =(JSONObject) new JSONTokener(result).nextValue();

        JSONObject feed = jo.optJSONObject("data");
        JSONArray entry = feed.optJSONArray("items");


        for(int i = 0 ; i<entry.length() ; i++){

        String title = entry.getJSONObject(i).getString("title");

        String thumbURL = entry.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("thumbnail").getString("sqDefault");
        Log.d("after get image", "ok")
        String   url;
        try {
            url = entry.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("player").getString("mobile");
        } catch (JSONException ignore) {
            url = entry.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("player").getString("default");
        }

        String description = entry.getJSONObject(i).getString("description");
        Log.d("after get description", "ok");
        videos videoobject=new videos();
        videoobject.setDecscrption(description);
        videoobject.setImageurl(thumbURL);
        videoobject.setVediourl(url);
        videoobject.setVideoname(title);

        videolist.add(videoobject);
        }
        listview.setAdapter(new custome(MainActivity.this,videolist));
        Log.d("AFTER set custome ", "before notify changes");


        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); 

        }catch(Exception exception) {
            Log.d("exception ", "nock nock nock....");
            Log.e("json ", exception.getMessage()); 
        }

            progressdialog.dismiss(); 
            super.onPostExecute(result); 

        } 




        String GetUrlBody (String Url ){

            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(); 

            HttpGet gethttp = new HttpGet(Url); 

            try{
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(gethttp); 

            if(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200){

                String save =
            EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity(), HTTP.UTF_8); 

                return save; 

            }else {
                return "Not Found"; 
            }

            }catch(Exception exception){}




            return null; 
        }



    }


}
```

And here is my costume list-view:

```
public class custome extends BaseAdapter {



    ArrayList<videos> data=new ArrayList<videos>();
    android.content.Context context1;
    android.widget.TextView name;
    ImageView  picture;

    public custome(Context context,ArrayList<videos>arrayList) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        context1=context;
       data= arrayList;
    }




    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return data.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return data.get(arg0);
    }

    public long getItemId(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return arg0;
    }

    public View getView(int arg0, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {
        View view=arg1;

        if(view==null)
        {   
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater=(LayoutInflater) _c.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            view=layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.listvideo,null); 
        }
        name=(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        picture=(ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

        videos video = data.get(arg0);
        name.setText(video.getVideoname());


        URL url = null;
        try {
            url = new URL(video.getImageurl());
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        try {
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        picture.setImageBitmap(bitmap);





        return view;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you use Thread to download image from network & get InputStream and then parse to Bitmap.
Full project is here:  [E4U Project](https://github.com/lucltv/e4u/tree/master/E4U)

```
import java.io.InputStream;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
      ImageView bmImage;

      public DownloadImageTask(ImageView bmImage) {
          this.bmImage = bmImage;
      }

      protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
          String urldisplay = urls[0];
          Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
          try {
            InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
            mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
          } catch (Exception e) {
              Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
              e.printStackTrace();
          }
          return mIcon11;
      }

      protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
          bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
      }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Tolen, The code in E4U Project which I gave you is exactly what you want. Get thumbnail from Youtube & Show to image view. And about The code which I gave you is an Asynctask to Download Bitmap from URL. & When download completed (onPostExecute()) we can set into ImageView

Comment: You can check out it from your Eclipse, Android Studio OR File ZIP

Comment: @:Jack Duong : Is this code need always the internet to get the image? in another words if the connection with the internet is not available this code return nothing? is this how things goes here?

Comment: Yes. But, This is just demo. You can use Catch or see this example: http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

Answer (score 1):

Downloading images from the net for display, with possible requirement of caching is a very common problem that many people have solved, I would strongly recommend you to use one of these tried and working solutions instead of rolling & debugging your own solution:

1. **Ion** (https://github.com/koush/ion) - very flexible and feature complete, plus it can download more than images but JSON, Strings, Files, and Java types as well. The part that I really like about this is that it can automatically cancel operations when the calling Activity finishes, so users don't waste time & bandwidth downloading images that will no longer be displayed
2. **Universal Image Loader** (https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) - equally capable for most use cases but for downloading/caching images only